# can't see the value in main function that I passed to another function in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy the content of a string from one variable to another. I don't get any error but nothing gets printed. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Following is the code:

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string strcopy(string &s1, string &s2)
{
     int i=0;
     for(i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
     s2[i]=s1[i];

     s2[i]='\0';
     return s2;
}

int main()
{
    string str1,str2;
    cout<<"Enter a string:";
    getline(cin,str1);
    str2=strcopy(str1, str2);
    cout<<str2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `string` is `std::string`, `s2` is initially a string with zero characters.   Your loop writes more data to it than it can hold, without any operation that resizes `s2` to hold the additional data. The behaviour of your code is therefore formally undefined. Since the behaviour is undefined, any explanation of what output you do or don't get is meaningless - all possibilities (no output, output you expect, something else) are possible.     You also need to `#include <string>` since that is not guaranteed with `#include <iostream>`  (so your code, as is, is not guaranteed to compile).

Comment: Are str1 and str2 std::string variables or are they C-style strings?

Comment: @AryanMediratta yes they are std::string variables, not C- style variables

Comment: @Peter thanks a lot for answering. what can I do additionally to prevent the extra data from being written to it?

Comment: Either resize `s2` so it can hold the same number of characters as `s1` (for example, `s2.resize(s1.length())+ 1)` if you insist on manually appending the trailing `'\0'`) or use operations which do that.     `std::string` has a working assignment operator so (unlike strings in C) can be assigned `s2 = s1` - that operator does the resizing.  Also, you don't need to handle a trailing zero separately.

Comment: @Peter thanks Peter for answering that. I was under the impression that like C, I was under the assumption that like C, there needs to be an explicitly mentioned trailing '\0' at the end in C++ strings as well. thanks for clarifying this

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `s2` (which is a reference to `str2`) out of bounds. The `std::string::operator[]` doesn't do any bounds check and it definitely doesn't increase the size of the string.

You seem to be doing a C-ish kind of string copying. In C++ that's not necessary. `std::string` has an `operator=`. Use it:

```
int main()
{
    std::string str1,str2;
    std::cout << "Enter a string:";
    std::getline(cin,str1);

    str2 = str1; // bam, so simple

    std::cout<<str2;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Another error in your code is that you don't include `<string>`. And I suggest to avoid `using namespace std`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I was not aware of the '=' operator. also, I wanted to pass the string to a user defined function which returns me the value in main function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    string str1,str2;
    cout<<"Enter a string:";
    getline(cin,str1);
    stusing namespace std;

string strcopy(string &s1, string &s2)
{
     //int i=0;
     //for(i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
     //s2[i]=s1[i];

     //s2[i]='\0';
    s2=s1;
     return s2;
}

int main()
{
    string str1,str2;
    cout<<"Enter a string:";
    getline(cin,str1);
    str2=strcopy(str1, str2);
    cout<<str2;
    return 0;
}
```